# Appending number to label names and assign value from Excel to caption through looping

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a format of labels in a word document as follows

```
<Name_Prod1>
<Curr_Cost1>
<Est_Cost1>


<Name_Prod11>
<Curr_Cost11>
<Est_Cost11>

<<Name_Prod12>
<Curr_Cost12>
<Est_Cost12>

<Name_Prod13>
<Curr_Cost13>
<Est_Cost13>
```

and so on...

My excel is of the format:

```
<S.NO> <Product name> <Current cost> <Est cost>
```

I want to go through the excel sheet and get the values and replace them in the caption of associated label.

My code is as follows. But I am not able to create a generic format to append the numbering to label name and loop through the label numbers.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:****.xlsx")
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer: j = 1

'For the first set 
ThisDocument.Name_Prod1.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Main Sheet").Cells(2, 2)
ThisDocument.Curr_Cost1.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Main Sheet").Cells(2, 3)
ThisDocument.Est_Cost1.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Main Sheet").Cells(2, 4)

'For the next set onwards
For i = 1 To i + 2 = 60
Dim ji As String
ji = j & i
'ji should be 11, 12, 13... as i increases
Dim np As Object: Set np = "Name_Prod" & ji
Dim cc As String: cc = "Curr_Cost" & ji
Dim ec As String: ec = "Est_Cost" & ji
ThisDocument.np.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Main Sheet").Cells(i + 2, 2)
ThisDocument.cc.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Main Sheet").Cells(i + 2, 3)
ThisDocument.ec.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Main Sheet").Cells(i + 2, 4)

Next


exWb.Close

Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Please help with some solutions

Comment: Does this work `ThisDocument.Name_Prod1.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Main Sheet").Cells(2, 2)` - do you get an error message or improperly formatted string? Examples are great for debugging

Comment: Yes the first set works

Comment: Try putting your variable names in array style - see answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have the syntax correct and you can compile this line without error

`ThisDocument.Name_Prod1.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Main Sheet").Cells(2, 2)`

Then you should be able to reference the other labels using the same method.
Just insert the variables into bracketed values for ThisDocument

`ThisDocument.np.Caption` becomes `ThisDocument(np).Caption`

`ThisDocument.cc.Caption` becomes `ThisDocument(cc).Caption`

`ThisDocument.ec.Caption` becomes `ThisDocument(ec).Caption`

Always a good idea to start your module with `Option Explicit` - then when you use `Debug | Compile` you can report on the line that causes the error message and add the error message to your question. These are keys to writing a good question that has a chance of being answered.